# When should i use Stored Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

When building a big application if i use single select, insert, delete will there be a break of my code.

Should I use stored procedures?

Note: Using PHP and mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other comments says, you should use stored procedures if you are sure you wont change the underlaying DBMS. Almost each DBMS has its own PL syntax so using stored procedures will make your application un-portable to other DBMS.

But, as it as also already been said, stored procedures will boost your performances, since on most DBMS they will be compiled and optimized by the DBMS engine.

For SQL injection protection, stored procedures are not the only solution: most high level decent database layers (such as PDO in PHP, JDBC in Java, or the DB2 python interface) will be able to do prepared statements. A prepared statement is a query you mean to re-use, the db managing layer will compile using the DBMS capabilities, and at call time will use parameters which can not inject code because the prepared query has already been compiled, making SQL injection virtually impossible. This depends on the DBMS and the high level DB functions you use of course.

Answer (score 1):

> When building a big application if i use single select, insert, delete will there be a break of my code.

Not as long as you have written your queries correctly meaning considering optimizations, avoiding sql injection.

> Should I use stored procedures?

Stored procedures are ideal in situation when you want/need to run same query on multiple pages. Think of them like functions that you **re-use** all around your application. The stored procedures also seem to have performance gain though.

Comment: SQL injection is security threat caused by poor queries and hackers can get access to your data. You can ready more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that stored procedures make it harder to scale the application (distributed database) and to change the database engine.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer "ALMOST ALWAYS"

Due to

1- SQL Injecton Attack

2- Code Reuse

3- Performance point of view

due to above points , should consider Stored Proc

**EDIT**

[SQL INJECTION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)